how to secure BE with 2 micro frontend one to be accessed publicly and one to be accessed with static ip
I have 2 microfrontends in amplify

first FE-A needs to be used from specific area (static ip)
second FE-B needs to be used from everywhere publicly

my issue is if i set 0.0.0.0 in Security Group of my EC2 both the FE will be accessible publicly.
if i use only static ip both the FE will have to be accessed from one place which raise the problem of FE-B not being accessible publicly
i tried setting up a lambda function to get the ip range in my region and update it in securty group of ec2 on daily basis and i know this is not optimim.
for the first FE-A when i setup static ip in SG of EC2 it works fine.
so i am not being able to meet the requirement of FE-A being closed system and FE-B being open.
I want a cost effective apporach to meet this requirements. It will be a great help if you guys can suggest me a fesable solution. my cloud provider is AWS

Can you confirm I have to correct understanding.
If you set the security group rule to 0.0.0.0/0 FE-A and FE-B are both publicly accessible.
But if you change the security rule to <static-ip>/32 then both FE-A and FE-B can only be access from that IP.
Is that correct?

Looks like they launched this service without being able to configure WAF. But that will probably change https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/36.

@b01 yes that is the issue

@b01 thank you for the update , well i was thinking there are ways to achieve but we are waiting for features to be added. thank you for the insight

Could you clarify what you mean by a micro frontend? Also, could you specify how to access each frontend?

hello @KavindaShehanRajapakshe i think i have clearly stated the FE are hosted in aws amplify, for microfrontends : frontends that are developed independent unlike monolith app. eg. SPA. here is a link https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html, which you can brows to learn more. For the problem i am facing its in the question.

Until they add a AWS managed prefix list and AWS Firewall support. I think using a Lambda to update the security group may be the most cost effective way.

Why did someone mark down this question?

Do you have an ALB in front of the EC2?

thank you @b01 yes i tried using lambda na updating the inbound but i think amplify team implmented firewall a week ago and i am using it now, Thank you for the help .
if anyone having the same issue please do follow this feature request and this github  issue:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/36#issuecomment-2561177811
